# Calculating monthly mean from daily netcdf file in python

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

Hello I have a netcdf file with daily data. Shape of the file is (5844, 89, 89) i.e 16 years data. I tried to get monthly average from daily data. I am looking for simillar to `resample` function in pandas dataframe. Is there anyways to do that in python. 
As I know it is very easy to calculate by using cdo and nco but I am looking in python.

Sample code that I used to read netcdf file is:

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
fh = Dataset(ncfile, mode='r')
time = fh.variables['time'][:]
lon = fh.variables['longitude'][:]
lat = fh.variables['latitude'][:]
data = fh.variables['t2m'][:]
data.shape
```

Comment: check out the resample functionality in xarray. It is built on top of Pandas' resample tools: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#resampling-and-grouped-operations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@ jhamman Thank you for suggesting [`xarray.resample`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html). It is simpler than I thought and the answer to my question is:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset(nc_file)
monthly_data = ds.resample(freq = 'm', dim = 'time', how = 'mean')
```

Answer (score 2):

by new versions of xarray, the usage is much more simple as follows

```
monthly_data=ds.resample(time='m').mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in Linux or macOS this can be easily done using nctoolkit, which uses CDO as a backend. (Installation instructions [here](https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)).

If you want to get the monthly mean, you just need the following:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
data = nc.open_data(ncfile)
data.tmean(["year", "month"])
```

This can be plotted:

```
data.plot()
```

If you wanted to convert it to a pandas dataframe:

```
df = data.to_dataframe()
```